# listview run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning,

I've been searching this community for errors like mine and found many similar ones but no quite the same. I'm trying to simulate a screen from a Rockwell HMI application in excel so I don't damage the HMI with my almost inexistent vba skills.

The goal with this is basically retrieve some data from sql and present it in a listview so, here is the code. Below there's a link showing where the error msg occurs. I tried a gazillion of different syntaxes and they all present different error msgs.

[code where the error happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgECO.png)

```
Private Sub Button1_Released()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim lstItem As ListItem
    Dim DateTimeStart As String
    Dim DateTimeEnd As String
    Dim MaxRows As Integer

    DateTimeStart = Format(Sheet1.DTPicker1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd")
    DateTimeEnd = Format(Sheet1.DTPicker2.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd")

    MaxRows = 5000

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source='ACAuditLog';User ID='User';Password='password';"
    Cn.Open

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    SQLStr = "SELECT [DateTimeOccurred], [UserName], [TagName], [ActionPerformed], [Comment] FROM [AssetCentre].[dbo].[vwAuditEventLogESign] WHERE [DateTimeOccurred] BETWEEN '" & DateTimeStart & "' AND '" & DateTimeEnd & "' ORDER BY [DateTimeOccurred] DESC" ' Enter your SQL here

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    With Sheet1.ListViewCtrl1
        'Set ListView style
        .View = lvwReport
        'This is not supported by ListView 5
        .Gridlines = True
        .FullRowSelect = True
        'Clear Header and ListItems
        .ListItems.Clear
        .ColumnHeaders.Clear
    End With

    'Set up column headers
    With Sheet1.ListViewCtrl1.ColumnHeaders
        .Clear
        .Add , "Date/Time Occurred", 700, lvwColumnLeft
        .Add , "User Name", 700, lvwColumnLeft
        .Add , "Tag Name", 700, lvwColumnLeft
        .Add , "Action Performed", 700, lvwColumnLeft
        .Add , "Comment", 700, lvwColumnLeft
    End With

    rs.MoveFirst
    MsgBox rs![DateTimeOccurred]
    Do Until rs.EOF
        Set lstItem = Sheet1.ListViewCtrl1.ListItems.Add()
        lstItem.Text = rs![DateTimeOccurred]
        lstItem.SubItems(1) = rs![UserName]
        lstItem.SubItems(2) = rs![TagName]
        lstItem.SubItems(3) = rs![ActionPerformed]
        lstItem.SubItems(4) = rs![Comment]
       'Next row
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: A good addition here would be the actual error message(s) you got when you ran your posted code.

Comment: + on which line is the error?

Comment: Set lstItem = Sheet1.ListViewCtrl1.ListItems.Add()

Comment: First time posting anything here. Apparently didn't do a good job on uploading the pictures I mentioned in post.

Comment: Try  `Dim lstItem As MSComctlLib.listitem`.  Does it help?

Comment: All right. It's working now! Thanks Domenic. Wonder however why it didn't work on excel if it works on the HMI?